# Update widget values from ajax function

Tags: plugins, widgets

I have widget like this

```
class Test extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'proreco',
            __('Product recommender', 'password_domain'),
            array(
                'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    // The widget form (for the backend )
    public function form($instance)
    {
       
        // Set widget defaults
        $defaults = array(
            'email' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'date' => ''
        );

        // Parse current settings with defaults
        extract(wp_parse_args(( array )$instance, $defaults)); ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('email')); ?>"><?php _e('Email', 'email_domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('email')); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('email')); ?>" type="email"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($email); ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('password')); ?>"><?php _e('Password:', 'password_domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('password')); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('password')); ?>" type="password"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr($password); ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p id="TEST"></p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit')); ?>"><?php _e('Limit', 'limit_domain'); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('limit')); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('limit')); ?>" type="number"
                   value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('date')); ?>">Date updated: </label>
            <?php
            echo esc_attr($date);
            ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button onclick="ExportData()" type="button">Export database</button>
        </p>

        <script>

            function ExportData() {
                var data = {
                    'action': 'export_database', // the name of your PHP function!
                };

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function (data) {
                        alertify.notify(data.errors, 'error', 5);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

    <?php }


    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {

    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {

    }
}
```

You will se that i have ajax function **export_database** that use to proceed some data. Is possible to update widget properties from this custom ajax function, not just submitting the form? Here is example of my ajax funcion

```
function export_database()
{   
    // HERE I HAVE TO UPDATE WIDGET PROPERTIES
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_export_database', 'export_database');  // for admins only
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_export_database', 'export_database'); // for ALL users
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you want to change? In general, you should understand that the common approach is to send some data with AJAX request, receive some data in response, and do some manipulations with the DOM on the user side via JavaScript according to received data.

Comment: And what is it exporting? Is the problem that it doesn't execute the JS? It isn't 100% clear what you're trying to do specifically, you mention widget properties but it's not clear which ones. Is there a reason you use the old ancient Admin AJAX API instead of making AJAX requests to the new modern/simple REST API? I would avoid using `extract`, it's a big code smell and can cause security issues with variable overwriting.

Comment: I am trying to call update($new_instance, $old_instance) from ajax

Comment: What i need is to update widget properties when I do ajax and not button submit from wordpress

Comment: Once again, that's not the way AJAX requests are used. You should receive all the data you need from AJAX response and change the user-side HTML with the JavaScript. You can receive the whole HTML block for your updated widget and then substitute the old widget contents with the new one, but you need user-side JS to do it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get something back from the ajax request, and then use what you get back to change what's shown in the widget? In other words, you don't want to just submit stuff to the ajax request, you want to get stuff back too?

Comment: @mozboz Whom are you asking, me or OP?

Comment: @IvanShatsky That i can not do, can you please make a answer, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean saying "update widget properties". What properties? How they should be updated?

Comment: $defaults = array(
            'email' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'date' => ''
        ); This properties i need to put custom properties here based on some values in ajax function, with ajax